# Xamarin Shell FlyoutItem's tab click event

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im using Xamarin forms, and on my AppShell, i want 2 tabs, i want to have a clicked event on one of the tabs, so that when clicked on it doesnt load another page but actually execute a function (show an Rg.Popup on top of the current page).

So i need a way to capture the tab clicked event or maybe a command or anything.

here is what i have:

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem" IsVisible="False">
    <Tab Title="001">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"></ShellContent>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="002">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProfilePage}"></ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class inherit from `TabBar` and override the method `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
 public class MyTab : TabBar
    {        
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (propertyName == "CurrentItem")
            {
                int index = this.Items.IndexOf(this.CurrentItem);
                
                if(index == 0)
                {
                    
                }
                if(index == 1)
                {
                    
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Use it in Xaml

```
 <local:MyTab>
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png" x:Name="tab1">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
</local:MyTab>
```

Another way I thought is that you can execute the function in the page's `OnAppearing` method.

Comment: but i need to use FlyoutItem and not TabBar,  because i need the flyout available to the user, can i still override FlyoutItem same as TabBar ?

Comment: OK, so I don't think you can detect the click event if FlyoutItem  so far.  Execute the function in the page's OnAppearing method would be a better choice.

Comment: Thats exactly what im trying to avoid, i need to only execute a function and not open any page

Comment: I would say no and the FlyoutItem is designed to open a page. You can have a try with [menu-items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#menu-items), it can execute a command.

Comment: ill use Flyout as  before, and use the PropertyChanged event, when i detect the tab ill open a page + a popup, but is there a way to do this if i could perhaps use a custom FlyoutItem ?

Comment: If you open a page, why not show the popup in the OnAppearing method? Another way is since you detect the click event, you can use messagingCenter to send message and execute method in other pages.

Comment: @RedZ Does my answer work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: I ended up calling a page and using the popup from the click event function (i cannot use the popup on OnAppearing)

Answer (score 3):

1 year too late but hope this helps. you can use menuItem which will display ontop of flyoutitem

```
<MenuItem Text="item" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" Clicked="OnClickMethod">
    </MenuItem>
```